# Invalid Constraint name when selecting CONSTRAINT_NAME from USER_CONSTRAINTS

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, ddl

I want to get all the canstraint_name  so i could generate  there ddl in java:
for each canstraint_name i'm going to execute :

```
DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,'CONSTRAINTS',true);
DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('CONSTRAINT','Constraint_name','hr');
```

I tried to execute this statement :

```
selectSQL = "SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS WHERE OWNER='" +Schemas+ "'";
```

I get a long list of constraints including invalid ones like: `pdpzZlEqTgUxb7qMBM8w==$0`

It generates an error when executing :

```
 DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('CONSTRAINT','pdpzZlEqTgUxb7qMBM8w==$0','hr')
```

> can't find pdpzZlEqTgUxb7qMBM8w==$0 in Schemas='hr' (the error it's in French)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message from GET_DDL suggest that those constraints belong to dropped tables (although those names start with `BIN$`). You cannot retrieve the DDL for those. If you don't want them you can do a

```
purge recyclebin;
```

before retrieving the constraints from `user_constraints`.

Or exclude them when retrieving the list of constraints:

```
SELECT constraint_name 
FROM user_constraints 
WHERE constraint_name NOT LIKE 'BIN$%';
```

---

This query:

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS WHERE OWNER='" +Schemas+ "'";
```

doesn't really make sense. `USER_CONSTRAINTS` will only list constraints owned by the current user. You will never get constraints from a different schema when using `USER_CONSTRAINTS`.

If you want to get constraints from a different schema, you need to use `ALL_CONSTRAINTS`.

If you do want the current user's constraints, you can safely remove the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Actually, according to the OP, these constraint's names don't start with `BIN$` and are therefore not in the recyclebin (although the `==$0` seems to suggest otherwise). So either the OP omitted the `BIN$` prefix, or they've got highly unusual constraint names.